# Create a function that finds how many prime numbers there are, up to the given integer

Tags: javascript, math, primes

```js
//Create a function that finds how many prime numbers there are, up to the given integer.
var numoffactor = 0
var count=0
function primenumber(str) {
    for (var i = 0; i < str; i++)
        for (var g = 0; g < i; g++) {
            if (i % g == 0) //if a factor is found
            { numoffactor++ }

        }
    if (numoffactor == 0) { count++ }
    return count
}
console.log(primenumber(9)) //showing 0 no matter what number I put in

console.log(numoffactor)//showing 12
```

My logic here is: starting from 0 to str, find the number of factors for each integer, for every i loop, if the number of factors is zero, then it's a prime number. But the output is 9 no matter the input. also the number of factors seems to be off.

Comment: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: count is not defined",`

Comment: where is `count` declare?

Comment: Sorry guys I forgot to paste it , now it's edited

Comment: What is `if (numoffactor == 0) { count++ }`  supposed to be doing? So if there are no numoffactor you increase the count outside the loop??

Comment: @epascarello if there is no factor for i then it's a prime number so I add the count for prime number by 1

Comment: @JiangYuxin but you never increase count

Comment: @epascarello actually I increase the count  if (numoffactor == 0) { count++ }

Comment: @JiangYuxin I was referring to the fact you do not increase count  anywhere else. The way you coded it, count is either going to be 1 or 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some point-

1. You don't divide a number by 0. Which is undefined.
2. All number is divisible by 1. So you don't check it.
3. You are not resetting `numoffactor` to `0` for every number.
4. First for loops brackets are missing. `numoffactor == 0` checking must be
   inside for loop.

```js
var numoffactor = 0
var count = 0
function primenumber(str) {
    if(str <= 1)
        return 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < str; i++) {
      numoffactor = 0;
      for (var g = 2; g < i; g++) {
          if (i % g == 0){
            numoffactor++;
          }
      }
      if (numoffactor == 0) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
}

console.log(primenumber(9))
console.log(numoffactor)
```

Here is another solution where you don't need to count number of factors.

```js
var count = 1
function primenumber(str) {
    if(str <= 1)
        return 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str; i++) {
      var g = 2;
      for (; g < i; g++) {
          if (i % g == 0)
            break;
      }
      if (i == g) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
}

console.log(primenumber(9))
```

Home this helps.

Comment: In the other solution, console.log(primenumber(11)) returns the wrong result

Comment: @John I don't think so, can you please explain?

Comment: The output doesn't display 11, although the count is correct which is what was asked. So, you were correct.

Comment: @RisulIslam I think both your answers are giving an incorrect result. Isn't `console.log(primenumber(9))` supposed to output 4 and not 5? Trying other inputs for both your examples gives the same error again.

Comment: @Ivan86 1, 2, 3, 5, 7 these are the prime numbers up to 9. There are some arguments regarding 1 is prime or not. Considering 1 is prime number my answers are right.

Comment: No, 1 is not prime! Both of your answers are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. The function `primenumber` runs the main for loop and keeps count of how many prime numbers were found, while the `isPrimeNumber` function checks to see if the current number is prime and returns true or false.

```js
function primenumber(str){
  let counter = 0;

  if(str <= 1)
    return 0;

  for(let i=2; i < str; i++) {
    if( isPrimeNumber(i) )
      counter++;
  }

  return counter;
}
 
function isPrimeNumber(num) {
  if( num == 2 )
    return true;

  for(let g=2; g < num; g++) {
    if (num % g == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}
 
document.write (primenumber(9));
```

Comment: if( isPrimeNumber(i) ) . do you mean if( isPrimeNumber(i) = true)?

Comment: ok I added that and now it's working fine. Just wondering if there is any single function solves the problem

Comment: @JiangYuxin I can easily make this a one-function thing. But it's messier. It's better to separate logic - it's easier to update and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a list of all primes within a range, are grab the length.

**Edit:** Updated to skip odd values, as [georg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/georg) suggested.

```js
const pushIf = (arr, value, fn) => { if (fn(value)) { arr.push(value) } }

const isPrime = (n) => {
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (n % i === 0) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return n > 1
}

const primes = (min, max) => {
  min = min || 2
  if (max === undefined) { max = min; min = 2 }
  let primeList = [], n = min
  if (n % 2 === 0) { // if min is even
    pushIf(primeList, n, isPrime)
    n++ // goto next odd
  }
  while (n < max) {
    pushIf(primeList, n, isPrime)
    n += 2 // skip odds
  }
  return primeList
}

console.log(primes(5, 10).length) // 2 (5 and 7)
console.log(primes(1000).length)  // 168
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
function primeFactorsTo(max)
{
    var store  = [], i, j, primes = [];
    for (i = 2; i <= max; ++i) 
    {
        if (!store [i]) 
          {
            primes.push(i);
            for (j = i << 1; j <= max; j += i) 
            {
                store[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return primes.length;
}

console.log(primeFactorsTo(9))
```